# Can I make a widget span more than one column in pyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I'd like something like this:

```
self.name_textbox.setColumnSpan(2)
```

Already tried putting everything else into one giant column.
Didn't work that well.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean? Are you referring to the spanning within a QGridLayout?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 2):

The row and column spanning cannot be set on the widget, as it's responsibility of the layout to do so.

In order to change the spanning of a widget that already is in a layout, just call `addWidget()` again with the new span value.

```py
class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        expandButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Expand')
        layout.addWidget(expandButton)
        expandButton.clicked.connect(self.expand)
        collapseButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Collapse')
        layout.addWidget(collapseButton, 0, 1)
        collapseButton.clicked.connect(self.collapse)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

    def expand(self):
        self.layout().addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0, 1, 2)

    def collapse(self):
        self.layout().addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0, 1, 1)
```